# Collection in compiled expression is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I want to use Expressions to create reusable stuff for EFCore.

For example I want to read the user id and the number of blogposts of a user:

```cs
   public static Expression<Func<UserA, UserBlogStats>> AsUserBlogStats
            => u => new UserBlogStats(u.Id, u.BlogPosts.Count);
```

This works very well if I use this expression directly in a query:

`db.Users.Select(AsUserBlogStats)`

My problem is, that `BlogPosts` is null, if I use the Expression in another Expression:

```
  public static Expression<Func<UserA, UserProfile>> AsUserUserProfile
            => u => new UserProfile(u.Id, u.Name, AsUserBlogStats.Compile().Invoke(u));
```

After Compile(), `BlogPosts` is `null` and I get a `NullReferenceException`.

How can I use an Expression in another Expression to reuse Expression as easy and efficient as possible?

Comment: I have had tried to accomplished a similar approach. End up using neinlinq.

Comment: so this is a limitation in EFCore and no Expression issue?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. By the way, you can check my question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058694/nested-expression-method-call-in-linq-select

Comment: Thanks; I dont like the approach to re-build all my expressions... I'll give LinqKit a try first...

Comment: @Ben What happens if you remove the `Compile()`?

Comment: @panoskarajohn same result

Comment: @Ben could you please provide how you call the expression `AsUserUserProfile`? You should not need `Compile` just `Invoke`.

Comment: @panoskarajohn I now Compile() is bad, but even with Invoke the BlogPosts collection is null.

Comment: @Ben I think your Issue is that BlogPosts is null coming from the query. This is why you get the null ref exception. Please make sure that you do not have nulls. This is not the Expression faults. YOu get null entries from your db

Comment: In the starting post I wrote that the collection in a >>simple expression<< is NOT null, but only in a >>nested expression<<.
Nevertheless you claim that the collection is null because of the database, which is (verified) not true. So please in future read the starting post carefully. Thank you.

Comment: @Ben based on the info we have. Your question is a guessing game. I read your question carefully enough. I just want the full picture. This is all i am saying. I think you should refactor you post and provide more info. So you get an appropriate answer. Please think, how can i reproduce your example?

Comment: @ilkerkaran thanks for your very very helpful hint. With the help of your old question I was able to solve my issue in a very very easy way with LinqKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an even better solution

AutoMapper supports Projections too, see [AutoMapper - Queryable Extensions](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ilkerkaran I tried to solved the problem with NeinLinq and LinqKit.

Since LinqKit is easier (Translate() of NeinLinq is too complicated here), I was able to solve my problem in a simple way.

```
   public static Expression<Func<UserA, UserBlogStats>> AsUserBlogStats
            => u => new UserBlogStats(u.Id, u.BlogPosts.Count);

   public static Expression<Func<UserA, UserProfile>> AsUserUserProfile
   {
      get
      {
         var userBlogStatsExpr = AsUserBlogStats; // local var required in Linqkit
         return u => new UserProfile(u.Id, u.Name, userBlogStatsExpr .Invoke(u));
      }
   }
```

and

```
db.Users.AsExpandable().Select(AsUserUserProfile)
```